# Scala monad to carry HTTP url/params around a Future[T]

Tags: scala, monads, json4s

I have implemented the following monad in scala which wraps a dispatch result with the URL and params used for the request

```
import org.json4s._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

case class Result[T](url:String,params:JValue,result:Future[T]) {
  self =>
  def flatMap[S](f: T => Result[S])(implicit executionContext:ExecutionContext):Result[S] = {
    val result_ = f andThen (_.result)
    Result(self.url,self.params,this.result flatMap result_)
  }

  def map[B](f: T => B)(implicit executionContext:ExecutionContext):Result[B] =
    Result(this.url,this.params,this.result map f )

}
```

The issue I am having is in the definition of `flatmap`. For `flatmap` to be correct, the `url` and `params` need to come from `f`, i.e. `f: T => Result[S]`. In the example above, although it compiles fine and the signatures are exactly what I need, the `self.url` and `self.params` means that the `url` and `params` are never being updated with the `Result` that is being `flatMap`ed, in other words, I don't know how to get the `url` and `param` variables from the application of `f` when `flatMap` is being called.

Although `T` is required for the `Request[S]`, it isn't required for the `url` and `params`, so what would be the scala way of separating out the `url,params` from the `result` so I can properly define `flatMap`?

Note: The general purpose behind the monad is so I can work with `HTTP` results from dispatch (i.e. `Future[T]`) while being able to carry around the `url` and `params` used for the request, with `flatMaps` updating the `url`, `params` and `result` (it being a new request), where as maps just modify the `result`

EDIT: Here is an example of how I am currently using the monad

```
  val restResponse = for {
    token <- Authenticate.Helpers.mainLogin // Type Result[String]
    userSessionToken <- Authenticate.Helpers.loginToken("someUser","somePassword",token) // Type Result[String]
    someOtherCommand <- DataService.getInitialData(token,userSessionToken) map
        (_ \ "someData" \ "someMoreData" \\ "evenMoreData" match {
          case JString(s) => s
          case JArray(items) =>
            items.collectFirst { case JString(s) =>s}.head
        }) // Type Result[String], the map is working over the `JValue` inside Future[JValue] that is held within the Request[JValue]
    someData <- DataService.getData(token,userSessionToken) // Type Result[JValue]
  } yield itemSummaries

  println(restResponse.url) // should print the url of someData, but is instead printing the url of token. restResponse.result is the correct value however
```

Note that before, this for comprehension just worked over `Future[T]`, however in doing so I lost the URL/params that are used

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have a deterministic `flatMap` if you're going to be basing the computation of `flatMap` on a non-deterministic outcome. Hence, you can't write `flatMap` as you'd like to write it.

Comment: What is the idiomatic way in scala to approach the problem I am trying to fix then? (i.e. 'tagging' a result with params/url while being able to treat `result` as a monad?)

Also `url` and `params` are deterministic, `result` is not.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical definition of `flatMap` is going to be something along the lines of:

```
def flatMap(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
```

which is deterministic in nature. In your case you're attempting to impose a deterministic composition over an action where the values needed are given in a non-deterministic manner. Hence, your troubles.

If you want to get back to that in a deterministic way, you'd have to use `Await`

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Result[B]): Result[B] = Await result (result map f)
```

which completely and totally defeats the purpose of using `Future` in the first place. A better way to characterize your object would be to simply remove the `Future` from within and enclose it from the outside:

```
case class Result(url: String, params: JValue, result: T){
  def map[R](f: T => R) = copy(result = f(result))
  def flatMap[R](f: T => Result[R]) = f(result)
}
```

Thus `Future` would enter the scene only through application to evaluating a function `(String, JValue) => Result[T]` asynchronously.

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't actually answer the original problem I have, which is being able to use (for example), for comprehension on a type `Result[T]`, while at the end being able to retrieve both the `result` as well as the `url` and `params`

With your solution, I have to unwrap the `Future[T]` to do any sought of comprehension, which means I lose the `url` and `params`

Comment: Have edited the original question with an example of how I use the `Result[T]` monad